# Does join change the sorting of original table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Does join change the sorting of original table?

For example

```
SELECT * FROM #empScheduled
```

AND

```
    SELECT es.job_code,es.shift_id, es.unit_id,jd.job_description,s.shift_description,u.unit_code,
     [group] = (SELECT job_description FROM dbo.job_desc WHERE job_code = jd.job_group_with),es.new_group 
     FROM #empScheduled es JOIN job_desc jd ON es.job_code = jd.job_code 
JOIN dbo.shifts s ON es.shift_id = s.shift_id JOIN dbo.units u 
ON es.unit_id = u.unit_id
```

Will produce the same records but in different sorting orders! Why does that happen and what is the way to stop it and produce the result in same sort order as the orginal table WITHOUT having to use Order by ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify an ORDER BY, there is no defined order on the result tuples. A simple `SELECT * FROM x` will return the tuples in the order they are stored, since only a table scan is done. However, if a join or similar is done, there is no way of knowing how the intermediate results are handled and the order of the results is undefined.

It is never a good idea to want the result "in the same order as the original table", since this is not a definition of an order. If you want to preserve the insert order, use an ascending primary key and simply order by that. This way, you can always restore the "original" order of your tuples.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you.

Comment: " A simple SELECT * FROM x will return the tuples in the order they are stored, since only a table scan is done" not necessaraily true. even select * from mytable will never have a guaranteed order.

Answer (score 3):

***There is no inherent sort order in SQL Server.***

In your case, it is likely due to indexes on your joined table and their sorted order.

If you want consistently sorted results, you must use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Many thanks. Even if there was no "default sort order" and just a table scan is done, would the database not do it exactly the same way even after joins.  Should I assume if the joined tables had no indexes, it will display the result in same sorted order as the original ones?

Comment: @user - never ever assume that your output will be ordered the same unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause.  It will depend a great deal on things that may change like the execution plan and what behind-the-scenes joins are used, which can change if your stats change on the tables over time.

Comment: @user503510,  you can never under any circumstances assume a sort order without defining an order by. It will not alawys return data even without a join in the order  the records were entered or even in the order of the clustered index. You CANNOT rely on some sort of implied sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the `FORCE ORDER` hint to explicitly force the join order. Otherwise the optimizer can order the joins any way it thinks is best. Not sure why you cannot use `ORDER BY` though.

Comment: Coul not use Order by because I dont have an identity column in the temp table. Nonetheless, could you explain how to use Force Order? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah never mind about FORCE ORDER. It's when you want to force the optimizer into join order when doing multiple joins. Since a relation in SQL (a set) is defined as having no order to its tuples (rows), the rows would come back unordered even if you were to invoke FORCE ORDER. You would just be forcing the optimizer to join a certain table first (based on the join order in the query).

Comment: @user503510, so add an identity definiton to the temp table if you want to use that for the sort order.